# Questions on formatting and clearing the rallymultiobjectpicker

Tags: rally

I am using the rallymultiobjectpicker to filter my grid but need some help on the following:

```
var cb = Ext.create('Rally.ui.picker.MultiObjectPicker', {
    modelType: 'Project',                    
    id: 'projectPicker',
    matchFieldWidth: false,
    editable:false,
    emptyText: "Project",
    //emptyCls: 'x-form-empty-field',
    placeholderText: "",
    loadingText: "",    
    width: 80               
});
```

1: How do I clear the selected values (the combobox has the clearValue method)?

2: I am using a non editable ObjectPicker and setting the empty text. I want to format the emptyText to be white with a background color using CSS styling. The background color displays perfectly, but the text color stays gray no matter what class I use!

```
.x-form-empty-field {
  color: #FFFFFF !important;
  background-color: #085478;  
}
```

4: How do I remove or hide the Search icon?

3: Is it possible to use a WsapiDataStore instead of a modelType as a data source?

I have struggled with this for days, any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: 1. Are you using the newly released 2.0rc1?  picker.setValue([]) should clear the selection for you. (This should also work in 2.0p5).

Can you post the code snippet for how you are adding the ObjectPicker for questions 2-4?

Comment: Kyle, thank you for your response, picker.setValue([]) works perfectly! I am using v 2.0p5 and have added the code snippet for my object picker at the top of my question. Help with questions 2 to 4 would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To clear the ObjectPicker selected values, ObjectPicker.setValue([]) works perfectly - thanks Kyle.

(I have opened a new question for queries 2and 4)